# How do I select a DOM item on a form dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular and a lot of my DOM items are given names dynamically according to some ID.

I want to set a select to invalid like this

```
form.nme112.$setValidity('required', false);
```

however I will only know its called nme112 until runtime which I can get but it will be in a string.. like "nme112". How can I then access it on the form?

Thanks
Luke

Comment: You can access properties with a string using bracket notation, like this: `form["nme112"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using

```
@ViewChild('selectInput') selectEl: ElementRef
```

then

```
let tmp: HTMLSelectElement = this.selectEl.nativeElement;
```

and then set the validity

html:

```
<select ... #selectInput/>
```